# The meta tag "close reason"

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

It looks like [close-reasons](/questions/tagged/close-reasons) has no tag information. In what respect does it differ from [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic)? Is the latter supposed to be used in general discussions and the former in accessing specific posts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [close-reasons](/questions/tagged/close-reasons) is for questions regarding the site-specific pre-defined close reasons you can find under *Close → Off-Topic.*
- [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic) is about what we consider on-topic on this site and what not.

As the pre-defined close reasons are only for common types of closure, not every discussion on on-topic-ness pertains to the close reasons. On the other hand, e.g., fixing a spelling mistake would only pertain to the close reasons, but not to what is on-topic or not.

I added a description explaining this to [close-reasons](/questions/tagged/close-reasons).